# is the sentence 她做练习做的很多 correct?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I've been practicing on my mandarin Chinese grammar workbook about the use of the 得 particle.

One of the last sentences is "她做练习做的很多", but I'm a bit perplexed because if I were to use 的, I would say " 她做练习的很多", whether with 得 I would say "她做练习做得很多" or "她练习做得很多".

Am I missing something?

Could someone also please explain to me the different meanings that 的 and 得  give to the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

她做练习做得很多 is grammatical. 得 (degree particle) should be followed by a degree and 很多 is indeed a degree.

Strictly speaking, [得， 的 and 地](http://blog.tutorming.com/mandarin-chinese-learning-tips/de-particles-in-chinese-grammar) have different functions, and should not be confused,  however, it has become a common practice for many Mandarin speakers to use them all interchangeably, so 她做练习做的很多 or 她练习做的很多 is also acceptable because 的 here is not a noun modifier but a replacement of 得 (verb modifier)

Answer (score 0):

I would omit the first 做 in favour of brevity.

她练习做得很多 would be grammatically correct.

Having said that, 练习 is more used as a verb rather than a noun. Hence a more fluent equivalent expression would be 她经常练习。

Comment: I like 她經常練習。The original 她做练习做的很多 sounds odd, though can be understood.

Answer (score 0):

她做练习做得很多 is correct. 多 describes 做 which is a verb，so use 得.
Translation: She did exercise (她做练习) and did much (做得很多)

她练习做得很多 is correct, same as 练习她做得很多
Translation: Regarding exercise (练习) she did much (她做得很多)

她做练习做的很多 is also correct. 多 describes 练习 which is a noun, so use 的.
Translation: The exercise what she did (她做的练习) is quite a lot(很多)

她做练习的很多 is not correct.

These forms which end with "很多" especially emphasize the meaning of quite a lot.

The most usual expression is:
她做了很多练习 or 她做了很多的练习
Translation: She did quite a lot of exercise.